# I ask for help with commands TransferFunctionModel + StateSpaceModel

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems, integral-transforms

Given system of ODE:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x}=G+u_1 \\ \dot{z}=-z+\frac{df}{dt} \\ \dot{G}=-G+z \cdot u_2 \end{cases}$

where $f=-x^2$,

$u_1=\frac{d}{dt}(\alpha \sin(\omega \cdot t))$ and $u_2=\alpha \sin(\omega \cdot t)$

```
f = -x[t]^2;
asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == G[t] + u1[t], z'[t] + z[t] == D[f, t], G'[t] + G[t] == z[t]  u2[t]}, {{x[t], 1}, {G[t], 0}, {z[t], 0}}, {u1[t], u2[t]}, {x[t], z[t], G[t]}, t];
```

And here is the result of the numerical calculation:

```
pars = {\[Alpha] = 0.5, \[Omega] = 2 Pi 5, xs = 1, xe = 0};
s1 = \[Alpha] Sin[\[Omega] t];
or = OutputResponse[asys, {D[s1, t], s1}, {t, 0, 500}]
Plot[{or[[1]] - s1, xe}, {t, 0, 25}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Next, I try to get the transfer function of the system:

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[asys]
```

And results:

```
or = OutputResponse[tf, {D[s1, t], s1}, {t, 0, 500}]
Plot[{or[[1]]}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

---

**Should the results be the same, and if not, why not?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course they are not going to be the same, because the linearization removed  all the nonlinear terms.

The responses are being computed for these two different systems.

```
NonlinearStateSpaceModel /@ {asys, StateSpaceModel[asys]}
```

[image]

Comment: Suba Thomasб hello! Thank you for your answer! I came across this question while trying to linearize a non-autonomous differential equation. I figured out the current question, but not yet with linearization.  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253133/linearization-such-system-of-ode

Comment: In this form, the system does not lend itself to linearization, because it has no equilibrium points. Maybe the original $\dot{x}=-x^2+\frac{1}{t+1}+1$ can be linearized? A comment was left there, it is not an option, because non-autonomy can be more complex and some more or less universal approach is needed.